# Chronograf set units for y axe

Tags: chronograf

I created a graph for interface statistic (in my custom dashboard), but it shows units like a numbers how I can change it to something like data rate `bits/sec`.

[image: custom graph]

Also when I saw graphs in default dashboard view it shows different units and it looks good.

[image: default chronograf view]

I'm using Chronograf 1.3.0

Comment: Custom dashboards do not support units yet. We will wait for new features. [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/issues/1536)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available as of Chronograf version **1.3.8.0**.

Modifying the units on your graphs can be done as follows, by version:

**Chronograf 1.3.8.x**

1. Click the caret at the top-right of a dashboard cell
2. Click `Edit`

   - [Image of `'cell caret > Edit'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC2yw.png)
3. Select the `Display Options` tab in the resulting overlay
4. Edit `Y Axis Controls` as desired
5. Click the Green checkmark at the top-right to save your work

**Chronograf 1.3.9.x**

1. Click the Pencil icon at the top-right of a dashboard cell

   - [Image of `Pencil` icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYe0t.png)
2. Select the `Options` tab in the resulting overlay
3. Edit `Y Axis Controls` as desired
4. Click the Green checkmark at the top-right to save your work